# using redis in python flask to live send messages

Tags: python, redis, flask, gevent

Below is a simple app to send mesg to the browser. if there is a new mesg from the redis channel it will be sent other wise send the last know value in a non-blocking way. 
But i am doing something wrong. can someone please help me understand

```
from gevent import monkey, Greenlet
monkey.patch_all()

from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for,abort,session,Response,jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)

myglobaldict = {'somedata':''}

class RedisLiveData:
    def __init__(self, channel_name):
        self.channel_name = channel_name
        self.redis_conn = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        pubsub = self.redis_conn.pubsub()
        gevent.spawn(self.sub, pubsub)
    def sub(self,pubsub):
        pubsub.subscribe(self.channel_name)
        for message in pubsub.listen():
            gevent.spawn(process_rcvd_mesg, message['data'])

def process_rcvd_mesg(mesg):
    print "Received new message %s " % mesg
    myglobaldict['somedata'] = mesg

g = RedisLiveData("test_channel")

@app.route('/latestmessage')
def latestmessage():
    return Response(myglobaldict,mimetype="application/json")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

on the javascript side i am just using a simple $.ajax get to view the messages.
but the client `http://localhost:5000/latestmessage` has the old message even after the redis update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the cache issue.

You can add a timestamp or a random number to the request `http://localhost:5000/latestmessage?t=timestamp` sent from the ajax.

Comment: If it's a cache issue, you can also set `SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT` to 1 in your Flask configuration (or any value low enough).

Comment: jquery has that builtin via the cache param :)

Comment: thanks guys. i am running this behind uwsgi and nginx and cache seems to be playing up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use POST instead of GET as http method, you eliminate the caching problem and some annoying behaviour from browsers like chrome where the requests after the first will wait for the first to complete before being sent to the webserver.

If you want to keep the GET method then you can ask jquery to make the request non cache-able by the browser with the setting parameter cache

```
$.ajax(..., {cache:false})
```